# Properly centering an <ul>

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to center an  horizontally, as in the object (box if you will) itself, not the text inside. I've tried many suggestions and followed many tutorials, yet nothing works... I finally ended up setting the margins myself, but I'd like it to adjust itself dynamically. This is the code I currently have:

```
.navbar { 
    margin:auto;
    margin-left:30em;
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:200;
}
.navbar li {
    float: left;
    display:inline;
    width:120px;
    text-align:center;
}
.navbar #left {
    left:0px;
    width:100px;
    height:35px;
    background:url('res/navigation.png') 0 0;
}
```

... and so on. The html is really simple, just the list with the corresponding class and id attributes.

Comment: why do you have `display:none` in the navbar styles?

Comment: it's taken care of by a script at load time

Comment: fair enough. However, note that the `display` style is relevant to the answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposed by many solution to set `margin: 0 auto;` doesn't work because you've got `position: fixed;` on your `ul` ;)

To my mind a good way of centering positioned elements is this:

```
.someelement{
    width: 600px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -300px; //here we put half of the element's width
}
```

A live example of this method can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/G8LrV/
The only problem with this method is that we set the fixed width.

If you have an element whose width **may change** - you'll probably have to calculate it dynamically by jQuery, for instance, and then set the negative margin.

A live example of it can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/G8LrV/1/

Answer (score 1):

Centering with CSS requires using `margin: 0 auto` -- as others have mentioned, and as I think you've already tried.

The reason this may not have worked for you is that it also requires the object to have a defined `width` and to have a block type `display` property (ie either `display:block` or `display:inline-block`).

It needs to be a `block` because only blocks can be manipulated in this way.

And it needs to have `width` because blocks default to 100% of the width of their container, which obviously leaves no room for it to be centered. The width can be a percentage rather than `px` if you want it to adapt to the size of the container, but it must be set.

If you're still struggling with it, try using Firebug (or similar) and examine what the browser thinks it's doing with the box. You may spot the problem here.

And if that doesn't help, create a JSFiddle example; this will help you see what's going on, and also give you something to show here.

Comment: It's impossible to center an `inline-block` element by `margin: 0 auto;`. Proof is here - http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/tjjWB/

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky, and you'll have to put the `<ul>` into a container. Then use the following css:

```
div {
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}
```

Where `div` is the container around `ul`.

[See this fiddle for live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VvHHe/1/)

Answer (score 0):

to center a div relative to its container you need to do

```
width:75%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

that way the object centers itself.

Comment: Already tried that, both adding it directly to the navbar class and surrounding the whole list by a navbar_container class and setting the margins to that instead. Didn't work...

Comment: set a width property. I bet it now expands to 100% which leaves no room to center.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an explicit width in order for the `margin:0 auto` to work.

Alternatively you can use some position trickery, as [seen  here](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/centered.html), for when the width is an unknown.

And you'll need to remove `display:none` from `.navbar` or you won't see anything; unless there's some other code at work that isn't included.

Comment: I have a JQuery script to do a nice fade-in on load, so the "display:none" is taken care of. I tried setting the width to both an amount of pixels (400px) and also a percentage (75%), nothing moved in the least.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the .navbar in a container using section or div then set the display property of the container to flex then justify-content property to center and giving the navbar a specific width. Something like this: 
`section or code{display: flex; justify-content: center; width: 300px;`

Answer (score 0):

Put the `.navbar` in a container using `section` or `div` then set the `display` property of the container to `flex` then `justify-content property` to `center` and giving the `navbar` a specific width. Something like this:

```css
section or code {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 300px;
}
```